# Calling calculus function from view in CakePhp?

Tags: cakephp, datetime

### Abstract

I would like to perform a calculus from `$start_date` and `$end_date` fetched from the MySQL table. Where should I put my calculus function to access it in my view?

---

### Detail

I am new to CakePhp. I have this Controller:

```
class PostersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Posters';
    function index (){ 
    $request  = $this->Poster->find('all');
    $this->set('posters', $request);
}
```

In my Posters MySQL table, I have `$start_date` and `$end_date` fields.
I want to have a function to perform a calculus for the duration using
this function.

```
function PosterDuration ($start_date, $end_date){
    $duration = $start_date->diff($end_date);
    return $duration;
}
```

I want to view the `$duration` in my View for each Poster. However I don't know where to put this function logic.

1. I thought to put it as a private function in my PostersController,
   however I don't know if I could access it from the `Posters.ctp` View.
2. I thought of creating a Component called `DuractionCalculusComponent`.
3. Could it be a behavior?

Since I am new in CakePhp, I have modest knowledge and don't know which option to chose.

Answer (score 0):

if it is only for presentation/output in the view layer, make it a helper and call it "on demand" for each record you display.

```
echo $this->Calculus->diff($date1, $date2);
```

if is needed in the controller/model level to work with in some kind it might be better suited as a behavioral approach or some afterFind() callback.

it really depends on the use case. so not much to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

When you've all the values are available in the controller. Just calculate the difference and pass the calculated result to your view by using set function or set compact.

```
$this->set('duration', $duration);
```

If you are using this at multiple places then you can go for helper. For that you need to pass the variables. Don's database form helper files. Its not a good practice.